# How to populate a WTForms SelectField with an ajax call (i.e. Select2)?

Tags: ajax, flask, jquery-select2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to implement a web app with Flask + WTForms + Select2 (ajax call), but unfortunately without great success. The main problem regards the attribute "choices" in one of my WTForms classes, because I can't understand how to populate the select menu with the ajax call and let WTForms class to manage these data.
This is my workaround:

```
class insertData(FlaskForm):
    ...
    feature_tag = SelectMultipleField(
        u'Features',
        choices=[(0, "")],
        coerce=int,
        render_kw={"multiple": "multiple"},
        id="feature_tag_sel2")
    ...
```

this is called in a template with:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    {{form.feature_tag}}
</div>
```

managed by Select2:

```
$("#feature_tag_sel2").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
      url: "/select/api/feature",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (params) {
          return { q: params.term };
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
          return {results: data};
      },
      cache: false
    }
});
```

and, finally, ajax call refers to this code:

```
@app.route('/select/api/feature')
def suggestion_feature():
    param = request.args.get('q', '')
    q = db.session.query(Feature).filter(Feature.nome_f.startswith(param)).all()
    value = [dict(id=i.id, text=i.nome_f) for i in q]
    return json.dumps(value)
```

When this code run, whatever the value of the select, `validate_on_submit`  rises an error: I can select the many values from Select2 menu but of course any value different for 0 is not a valid choice. Then I tried to stop the propagation of this error by implementing a new field definition:

```
class Select2MultipleField(SelectMultipleField):
    def pre_validate(self, form):
        # Prevent "not a valid choice" error
        pass
```

This code works, but in any case it is a workaround. For instance, when `validate_on_submit` finds another error in the form and the page is reloaded, all the selected values are lost. The same happens when I need to edit data. In sum, this workaround make me lose the many advantages of WTForms.

The question thus is: is there any method to integrate a WTForms SelectField with data retrieved with an ajax call?

**EDITED 10/08/2021**

For anyone still interested in the matter, I found the following solution: [Flask-Select2](https://github.com/pjcunningham/Flask-Select2). It integrates very well into the code with very little modification. The only flaw is that it works well out of the box only with Select2 ver. 3 (for an update to the current version of Select2 there are several points to rewrite)

Comment: have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your issue, you have got two issue with your ajax select2 with WTForm.

- Not a valid choice when submitting a form
- and selected value lost and form reload or error

Let me try to solve them as the followings:

#### Not a valid choice when submitting a form

For the first issue of not a valid choice, you can tell wtf form not to validate it on submitting form, yeah your workaround solution! it works for me too.

```
class Select2MultipleField(SelectMultipleField):
    def pre_validate(self, form):
        # Prevent "not a valid choice" error
        pass
```

#### selected value lost and form reload or error

Quoted from your question

> when validate_on_submit finds another error in the form and the page
> is reloaded, all the selected values are lost. The same happens when I
> need to edit data.

Yeah, this does works as expected.First the select field does not contain any option since all of data from your select field was getting from remote ajax call, meaning the select field was not provided any data choice when you created with WTForm call as your code here

```
class insertData(FlaskForm):
    ...
    feature_tag = SelectMultipleField(
        u'Features',
        choices=[(0, "")],
        coerce=int,
        render_kw={"multiple": "multiple"},
        id="feature_tag_sel2")
    ...
```

Indeed, you don't have to provide argument `choices` since your data was called from remote ajax call and you already solve issue `Not a valid choice` already.

To answer to your question and solve this second issue, you can check if data value was attached with your select field like below, and create it as an option for your select field as this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    {{form.feature_tag}}
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#feature_tag_sel2").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
      url: "/select/api/feature",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (params) {
          return { q: params.term };
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
          return {results: data};
      },
      cache: false
    }
});

{# check if select field come with data previously selected #}
{% if form.feature_tag.data %}
{# trigger an ajax call to url with parameter of this value #}

        $.ajax("/select/api/feature?q={{form.feature_tag.data}}", {
                dataType: "json"
        }).done(
                function(data) { 
                    text = data.items[0].text // text returned from your url
                    id = data.items[0].id. // id returned from your url
                    
                    // created an option for the select field
                    var newOption = new Option(text, id, false, false)

                    $('#{{form.feature_tag.id}}').append(newOption).trigger('change')

                    $('#{{form.feature_tag.id}}').val(id).trigger('change')
    
                }
        );

{% endif %}


});

</script>
```

This way, your select field should already contain a value of your previously selected before either when you viewing it or editing it :)

Hope this help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a few years old but I had a similar requirement but I wanted a pure javascript (no jquery) alternative to select2. I found this in the form of tom-select https://tom-select.js.org

I created a custom widget based on code from flask-admin.

```
from wtforms import widgets
from flask.globals import _request_ctx_stack
from flask_admin.babel import gettext, ngettext
from flask_admin import helpers as h

__all__ = ['TomSelectWidget','RenderTemplateWidget', ]



class TomSelectWidget(widgets.Select):
    """
        `TomSelect <https://tom-select.js.org/docs/>`_ styled select widget.
        You must include tom-select.complete.js,and tom-select stylesheet for it to
        work.
    """
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('data-role', u'tom-select')

        allow_blank = getattr(field, 'allow_blank', False)
        if allow_blank and not self.multiple:
            kwargs['data-allow-blank'] = u'1'

        return super(TomSelectWidget, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)


class RenderTemplateWidget(object):
    """
        WTForms widget that renders Jinja2 template
    """
    def __init__(self, template):
        """
            Constructor

            :param template:
                Template path
        """
        self.template = template

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        ctx = _request_ctx_stack.top
        jinja_env = ctx.app.jinja_env

        kwargs.update({
            'field': field,
            '_gettext': gettext,
            '_ngettext': ngettext,
            'h': h,
        })

        template = jinja_env.get_template(self.template)
        return template.render(kwargs)
```

Then for my feild I used QuerySelect, here's my example:

```
followed_by = QuerySelectField(label="Followers",
                               query_factory=lambda: User.query.order_by(User.full_name.asc()),
                               widget=TomSelectWidget(),
                               render_kw={'class': 'form-control'},)
```

In your jinja template include css and javascript for tom-select as per the documentation (link above). I just grabbed these from jsDelivr.

Then to initalise in your javascript like so:

```
new TomSelect('#followed_by',{
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    maxItems: 10,
    maxOptions: 100,
    create: false
});
```

or you if you have multiple selects on the same page initialise by class:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.select').forEach((el)=>{
    let settings = {maxItems: null,};
    new TomSelect(el,settings);
});
```